# how to Create a date input that only accepts a date that comes after today

Tags: javascript, html

I want to Create a date input that only accepts a date that comes after today, and if the user selected a date that comes before today you have to display an error message that describes that they can't do that.

what should i add to my code :

```js
var myForm = document.getElementById('my_form');
myForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    var errors = "";
    var ageInput = document.getElementById('age_input');
    var nameInput = document.getElementById('name_input');
    if (!ageInput.value || isNaN(ageInput.value))
    {
      ageInput.style.borderColor = 'red';
      errors += 'age is invalid</br>';
    } else {
      ageInput.style.borderColor = 'inherit';
    }
    if(!nameInput.value) {
      nameInput.style.borderColor = 'red';
      errors += 'name is invalid\n';
    } else {
      nameInput.style.borderColor = 'inherit';
    }
    if (errors){
     document.getElementById('errors').innerHTML = errors;
     // to prevent the page from reloading
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

```html
 <form id="my_form" action="submit.php">
      <label>Age: </label>
      <input type="text" id="age_input" />
      <label>Name: </label>
      <input type="text" id="name_input" />
      <label>date: </label>
      <input type="date" id="date_input" />
      <button type="submit">submit</button>

 

      <p id='errors'></p>

    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const datePicker = document.getElementById('date_input');
const selectedDate = new Date(datePicker.value);
const today = new Date();
today.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);

if (isNaN(selectedDate) || selectedDate < today) {
  errors += 'you can pick dates from the past</br>';
}
```

Comment: did not work, the code still run and did not give any warning

Comment: @adnan Ah, the problem was when no date was selected, I updated the answer

Comment: Sorry, but still runs with out checking  the date

Comment: my bad , it works but i should put the code before preventDefault()